# How can I subset rows from data.table with applying conditions by group?

Tags: r, data.table

I am using

```
baseT[
    Zone.Type=='response_button_text' & Spreadsheet.Row %in% which(sst$randomise_trials==1),
    Reaction.Time>(median(Reaction.Time)+3*mad(Reaction.Time)),
    by=c("Correct","Spreadsheet.Row")
    ]
```

to extract rows that have reaction.time greater then median+3mad `by` groups(`c("Correct","Spreadsheet.Row")`), but it doesn't give columns other than those specified in the `by` parameter and a result column - `V1`, like below:

```
      Correct Spreadsheet.Row    V1
   1:      -1               7 FALSE
   2:      -1               7 FALSE
   3:      -1               7 FALSE
   4:      -1               7 FALSE
   5:      -1               7 FALSE
  ---                              
1706:      -1              11 FALSE
1707:      -1              11 FALSE
1708:      -1              11 FALSE
1709:      -1              11 FALSE
1710:      -1              11 FALSE
```

I want the whole rows or at least another 'ID' column. I think there is a simple syntax solution. Can anyone please give some hints?

Comment: Please provide sample data so that we can see what you start with, and include your expected output given that sample input. Please don't try to post all 1710 rows of data, a subset should be sufficient, please make sure there is enough variability in `Correct` and `Spreadsheet.Row` for the grouping to be fruitful, perhaps 2 in each. (Either post the output from `dput(x)` or make the data programmatically with `data.table(...)`.) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Just to mark I figuring it out myself long time ago.

Just add `ID=ID` to the second parameter and surround it with .() like below:

```
...,.(ID=ID, Reaction.Time>(median(Reaction.Time)+3*mad(Reaction.Time))),...
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a new column whilst keeping the original ones, use the `:=` syntax:

```
a = as.data.table(mtcars)
a[mpg>20, mean_mpg := mean(mpg), by=carb]

     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb mean_mpg
 1: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    21.00
 2: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4    21.00
 3: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    26.55
 4: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1    26.55
 5: 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2       NA
 6: 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1       NA
 7: 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4       NA
 8: 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2    25.90
```